# How to integrate $\cos t e^{-t^2/2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'd like to solve the D.E. $$y'=xy+\cos{x}$$

where $y(0)=1$. So, with Cauchy formula I get

$$e^\frac{x^2}{2}\left(C+\int \cos{t}\cdot e^\frac{-t^2}{2}dt\right) $$

So the question is how to solve this integral?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5Bcos+x+Power%5Be%2C-Divide%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%2C2%5D%5D%2Cx%5D

Comment: Sorry, I supposed to add here this condition y(0)=1.

Comment: Note that the vast majority of integrals are not solvable in terms of elementary functions, such as $\int e^{-x^2}~dx$, $\int \cos(x^2)~dx$, $\int x^x~dx$ and this one. If you are comfortable with (imaginary) error functions, you can give an expression in terms of those functions (as done by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+cos%28x%29*e%5E%28-x%5E2%2F2%29)) but apart from that there is little you can do other than simply writing the solution as
$$y(x)=e^{x^2/2}+e^{x^2/2}\int_0^x \cos(t)e^{-t^2/2}~dt.$$

Answer (score 3):

The solution to your differential equation is, using the method of integrating factors,
$$y(x)=e^{x^2/2}+e^{x^2/2}\int_0^x e^{-t^2/2}\cos(t)\,dt$$
You have that
$$\frac{y(x)}{e^{x^2/2}}\to1+\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\cos(t)\,dt=1+\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2e}}\qquad \text{ as } x\to\infty.$$
Hence,
$$y(x)=e^{x^2/2}\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2e}}\right)+o\big(e^{x^2/2}\big).$$
We can be more precise about the error term $o\big(e^{x^2/2}\big)$. Denote
$$R(x)=\left|y(x)- e^{x^2/2}\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2e}}\right)\right|.$$
Thus we have that
$$
\begin{aligned}
R(x)&\le e^{x^2/2} \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt\\
&\le \frac{1}{2} e^{x^2/2} \int_{x^2}^\infty e^{-t/2}t^{-1/2}\,dt \\
&\le \frac{1}{x}.
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\cos (t)\,e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \cos (t)\,dt=\Re\int e^{it} \,e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \,dt$$

Completing the square
$$\int e^{it} \,e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \,dt=\int e^{-\frac{t^2-2it+i^2+1}{2}} \,dt=\frac 1{\sqrt e}\int e^{-\frac{(t-i)^2} 2}\,dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2 e}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{t-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2 e}} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{t-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{t+
   i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Nice answer. (Btw, I think you have an extra $\cos(t)$ in the integrand in your first line :P)